# Parse html (potentially not well-formed) without downloading the whole in Java

Tags: java, html

I'm looking for a way to read and parse partial html file from the `InputStream`.
Say the input is like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta something="something">
```

The ideal solution would be after seeing that tag, store it somewhere and close the connection. In this case the HTML may not be well formed (since we only got partial of it), so the xml parsers may fail. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSoup`](http://jsoup.org/)

```
String partialHtml = "<html><head><meta something=\"something\">";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(partialHtml);
Elements values = document.getElementsByAttribute("something");
for (Element el : values) {
    System.out.println(el.attr("something"));
}
```

Comment: Well, not really, with this approach you would have to download chunks and do a parse each time

Comment: It seems that I can use a buffered reader to read the content. Thanks.